# PHP json_encode include brackets for arrays

Tags: php, json

I am using `json_encode` to convert PHP arrays to json and it seems to work fine except for one thing.

If I have a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
$person = array(
  'name' => 'John Smith',
  'age' => 36,
  'siblings' => array(
    'male' => array('John Doe','Mark'),
    'female' => array('Jane Doe','Jane Smith')
  )
);
```

I want it to put brackets around `siblings` but it only does it around `male` and `female`, i.e:

```
{
  "name":"John Smith",
  "age":36,
  "siblings":{
    "male":[
      "John Doe",
      "Mark"
    ],
    "female":[
      "Jane Doe",
      "Jane Smith"
    ]
  }
}
```

And I want `"siblings":[{ ... }]`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$person = array(
  'name' => 'John Smith',
  'age' => 36,
  'siblings' => array(array(
    'male' => array('John Doe','Mark'),
    'female' => array('Jane Doe','Jane Smith')
  ))
);
```

This will give exactly what you want but it doesn't make much sense

Comment: Hmm... that actually does work. It's for creating `manifest.json` files for chrome and they require it to be in this format.

Comment: @barjonah: if they require it - then it makes sense, indeed

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not support assosicative arrays, therefore assosicative arrays are converted to objects.

But you can iterate over objects like you can iterate over arrays.

```
var i, j;
for (i in siblings) {
   for (j = 0; j < i.length; i++) {
       i[j];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$person = array(
  'name' => 'John Smith',
  'age' => 36,
  'siblings' => array(
    array(
      'gender' => 'male',
      'name' => 'John Doe',
    ),
    array(
      'gender' => 'male',
      'name' => 'Mark',
    ),
    array(
      'gender' => 'female',
      'name' => 'Jane Doe',
    ),
    array(
      'gender' => 'female',
      'name' => 'Jane Smith',
    ),
  )
);
```

Comment: This also works, but seems like a lot more work compared to zerkm's answer.